# How to import a file in a Java gradle project

Tags: java, file, gradle

I have already read many guides and forums about it but I still haven't succeeded.
The file must be in the project folder because it is a project for the university.
I need to transform the contents of the file into a string so that I can then manipulate it as I need.
If anyone can kindly show me the best way to do it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to read file content. Please try:

```
List<String> file = Files.readAllLines(Path.of(yourPath));
```